# XML and the & character

Tags: c#, xml

I need to pass the & character inside an XML element, but its not liking it, here is a code sample:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement batch = doc.CreateElement("Batch");
string item = "<field>http://mylink.com/page.aspx?id=1&disp=2</field>"
batch.InnerXml = item;
```

Its absolutely crucial I put this link inside, so does anyone know how to get around this?

Thank you

Comment: why use an xmlwriter, then decide to write out xml manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape it: `&amp;`.

```
string item = "<field>http://mylink.com/page.aspx?id=1&amp;disp=2</field>";
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to escape it as `&amp;`.

Answer (score 8):

As people are saying, escaping the element will work.  However, I find this a little cleaner:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement batch = doc.CreateElement("Batch");
XmlElement field = doc.CreateElement("field");
string link = "http://mylink.com/page.aspx?id=1&disp=2"
field.InnerText = link;
batch.AppendChild(field);
```

Answer (score 4):

Escape it as `&amp;`. This is called HTML/XML Entities. See more information and list of others entities [here](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

The code should look like this:

```
string item = "<field>http://mylink.com/page.aspx?id=1&amp;disp=2</field>"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use &amp;

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, you can just use an `&amp;` escape sequence. However, the more elegant approach is not to deal directly with the XML at all.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var batch = doc.CreateElement("Batch");
var field = doc.CreateElement("field");
field.InnerText = "http://mylink.com/page.aspx?id=1&disp=2"
batch.Children.AppendChild(field);
```

No need to worry about escaping anything, this way. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement batch = doc.CreateElement("Batch");
string item = "<field>http://mylink.com/page.aspx?id=1&amp;disp=2</field>"
batch.InnerXml = item;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create the element with the Xml methods it will wrap everything up nicely for you.  So use the `CreateElement` method again and set the `InnerText` property of the element to your link.

Answer (score 2):

Use .InnerText rather than .InnerXml, and the XmlDocument instance will do all necessary encodings for you, like automatically escaping the & to &

The .InnerXml is used when the string you have is already valid xml which is not to be escaped, which is not the case here.